# Why does the Scanner class return \n as the first newline character on IntelliJ+Windows?

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, input, newline

When I run the following class from *IntelliJ* on a Windows 10:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String ... args)
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        reader.useDelimiter("");
        String s = reader.next();
        System.out.println((int)s.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

and I press the `Enter` key as the input, the output is:

```
10
```

This baffles me, since the Windows line separator is the 2 character sequence `\r\n`. Why isn't the output

```
13
```

?

Comment: Curious: have you checked the raw `InputStream` (just `System.in`)?  Does it contain a carriage return?

Comment: Also: run this code on the command line w/ no IDE.  IntelliJ may be doing things differently that the Windows OS.

Comment: I get 13 when running this in Eclipse. But you should try running from the command line.

Comment: If your Scanner will read fixed data like `Scanner reader = new Scanner("\r\n");` it returns `13` (so \r) and 10 (\n). My guess is that your IDE is set to have only `\n` as line separator (even if it runs on Windows).

Comment: Seems like a bug. I have created a bug report here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-315253/.